# Is there a way to loop through a list and convert everything to integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a programme that calculates the average out of a list of grades and prints it out along with the student's name, but I'm getting a type error when I try to sum all the grades and divide them by the length of the list. This is what I have:

```
def average_grade(afile):
    aline = afile.readline()
    grades = []
    while aline:
        info = aline.split()
        grades = info[1:]
        average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
        print(info[0],average)
        aline = afile.readline()

my_file = open('studentdata.txt','r')

average_grade(my_file)

my_file.close()
```

This is the content of the file:

```
joe 10 15 20 30 40
bill 23 16 19 22
sue 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17
grace 12 28 21 45 26 10
john 14 32 25 16 89
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "averagegrade.py", line 13, in <module>
    average_grade(my_file)
  File "averagegrade.py", line 7, in average_grade
    average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Is it possible to convert everything in `grades` to an integer using list traversal or would I have to write several more lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading numbers as *strings*, you must convert them to `int`s before adding them:

```
grades = [int(x) for x in info[1:]]
average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew the problem was that the numbers were strings but I couldn't figure out how to convert them without having to write another 4-5 line function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

In your code, you would simply use:

```
average = sum(map(int, grades)) / len(grades)
```

Comment: Why use `list` on `map` if a list comprehension does the job?

Comment: Because I was addressing the title generally. My edit (maybe after your comment? not sure), shows it in the code without `list`

Comment: @Hyperboreus, there, I just removed the previous example entirely

Comment: Looks better to me (me presonally). Although I think that `sum(int (grade) for grade in grades)` is more readable and intuitive. And as `import this` says: "Readability counts.".

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, when you read from a file you get back strings, no matter that there are actual numbers in the file.

Here is a cleaned up version that's a bit more Python-like (Python 3 required):

```
import fileinput

def average_grades():
    for line in fileinput.input():
        name, *grades = line.split()
        grades = [int(grade) for grade in grades]
        average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
        yield name, average

if __name__ == '__main__':
    avgs = ("{} {:.2f}".format(name, avg) for name, avg in average_grades())
    print(*avgs, sep='\n')
```

This way you can call your script with the studentdata file(s) as argument:

```
python3 avg.py studentdata.txt
```